# Execute some action when Spock test fails

Tags: testing, spock

I'd like to execute some action when Spock test fails. Specifically, take a screenshot. Is it possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a listener class

```
class ExampleListener extends AbstractRunListener {

  def void error(ErrorInfo error) {
    println "Actual on error logic"
  }
}
```

then add it to each specification using implementation of `IGlobalExtension` that is executed for each Spec

```
class GlobalSpecExtension implements IGlobalExtension {

  @Override
  void visitSpec(SpecInfo specInfo) {
    specInfo.addListener(new ExampleListener())
  }
}
```

and finally create file named `org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension` in your `META-INF/services directory` (typically it will be under `src/test/resources` if you are using Maven) with the full name of your `IGlobalExtension` implementation e.g.

```
com.example.tests.GlobalSpecExtension
```

Comment: What is the rational behind creating a file with the name of the package in the services directory?

Comment: @eddyrokr the file is there so spock knows how to find the class and load it and run it.  It's either a "well named file" or "scan whole classpath", so almost everyone goes w/ well-named file.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve this is to write a (global or annotation-driven) Spock extension that implements and registers an `AbstractRunListener`. For an example, see [OptimizeRunOrderExtension](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/groovy-1.8/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/runtime/extension/builtin/OptimizeRunOrderExtension.java). For how to register a global extension, see the [IGlobalExtension](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/groovy-1.8/spock-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension) descriptor.

There isn't much documentation on extensions because the APIs are still subject to change. If you want to play it safe (and can live with some restrictions), you can implement a [JUnit Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) instead.

One problem that you may encounter in both cases is that they don't provide access to the current spec instance. If you need this, you may have to use both an `AbstractRunListener` (to be notified of the failure) and an `IMethodInterceptor` (to get hold of the spec instance), both registered by the same extension. (Shouldn't be this hard, but that's what's currently there.)

Comment: Hi Peter! How would I go about combining these two in order to invalidate and maybe recreate a broken driver instance? In cloud tests if I receive something like `WebDriverException: Session [...] was terminated due to TIMEOUT` I can intercept and log the error in the listener, but do not have access to `driver` or a driver factory the cache of which I can invalidate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to do it this way:

```
class ExampleTest extends GebSpec{

    static boolean success = false

    def setup(){
        success = false
    }

    def cleanup(){
        assert success == true, someAction()
    }

    def someAction(){
    }

    def "TestCase"(){
        expect:
        /*What you expect here*/

        (success = true) != null
    }
}
```

Before each test case "success" is set to false by the setup() method.
At the end of each test case you add the "(success = true) != null" statement. Therefore "success" will only be true if the test case has passed.
After each test case the cleanup() method will verify if "success" is true. If it isn't the method someAction() will be called.

Answer (score 0):

I can't upvote or comment on user3074543's answer, but it's simpler than creating an extension. I want easy. So I shortened user*'s a little (I don't mean the 1-line methods). You can make the logic simpler by recording failure instead of success, and reduce typing with a done() helper.

```
class Test extends spock.lang.Specification {
    def fail
    def setup(){ fail = true }
    def done(){ !(fail = false) }
    def cleanup(){ fail && doStuffWhenFail() }
    def 'test things'(){
        expect:
        stuff
        done()
    }
}
```