# How to Generate extent report in Geb & Spock

Tags: report, spock, geb, extentreports, extent

We are using Geb and Spock framework for testing web application and integrated with an extent report. We have created a separate class for extent report functionalities using JUnit `@Rule` to access among all Test cases. Now the problem is when `TC` fails, it's not generating a report for a failed scenario, instead it's creating a report for succeeded case. Is there any way to catch `TestWatcher` failed exception using Spock TC's. Or is there any similar class like `TestWatcher` in Spock which performs below functionality.

```
@Rule
    public TestRule watchman = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return super.apply(base, description)
    }
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e,Description description) {
        TestUtils.takeScreenshot("testimg", "png", driver)
        println("fail")
        ExtentReports extent = createReport()
        ExtentTest test = extent.startTest(description.getMethodName(), "Test failed, click here for further details")
        // step log
        String img = test.addScreenCapture(".testimg.png")
        test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Failure : "+ e.toString(),img)
        flushReports(extent, test)
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
        ExtentReports extent = createReport()
        ExtentTest test = extent.startTest(description.getMethodName(), "-")
        test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Passed")
        flushReports(extent, test)
    }

    @Override
    protected void skipped(AssumptionViolatedException e, Description description) {
        ExtentReports extent = createReport();
        ExtentTest test = extent.startTest(description.getMethodName(), "-")
        // step log
        test.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Skipped")
        flushReports(extent, test)
    }

    @Override
    protected void finished(Description description) {
        browser.close()
    }
}
private ExtentReports createReport() {
    ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports(".testReport.html", false);
    return extent
}
private void flushReports(ExtentReports extent, ExtentTest test){
    extent.endTest(test)
    extent.flush()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spock has some basic support for JUnit rules.

If your particular case does not work you need to write a Spock extension that gives you hookups to the test lifecycle.

See also [Execute some action when Spock test fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420034/execute-some-action-when-spock-test-fails)