# How to add directory to a classpath , I am trying to register IGLOBAL Extension in spock

Tags: automated-tests, spock

How to add directory to a classpath ? I am trying to register IGLOBAL Extension in spock.

Not sure about the below step what exactly I should be doing:
**Extensions are not discovered automatically, you must create a special org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension file under META-INF/services directory on the CLASSPATH (of course it can be in a different JAR). The content of that file is simply a fully qualified name of the extension class**

I am not sure how to add the file on the classpath

Comment: What is unclear about this explanation? Have you tried doing what it says? Besides, what kind of build system are you using? Maven? Gradle? Or is is a plain IDE project? In the latter case, which IDE? Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: Besides, you could have linked to the tutorial blog post you are trying to follow: https://nurkiewicz.com/2015/10/spock-vw-writing-custom-spock-framework.html. The corresponding Spock manual chapter is https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M1/all_in_one.html#_writing_custom_extensions.

Comment: I am using a plain simple ide project ... I am trying to follow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666160/find-the-outcome-status-of-a-test-in-specification-cleanup.   What i dont understand on how to do is :: How to register the Spock extension:

You also need to add the file META-INF/services/org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension to your test resources in order to register the extension. The file simply has this content:

de.scrum_master.testing.extension.TestResultExtension..      we are not using maven or gradle ...

Comment: I cant say it a simple ide project .. test solution is along with the dev project which is in grails ..no maven or gradle is used ...we are using grails for building the solution , both dev code base and testing codebase is under a single solution as multiple projects ..IntelliJ is the IDE used

Comment: Sorry, that is not enough information for me to help you. Did you read my links about how to ask questions? My other Stack Overflow answer you linked to should also contain enough information for you to solve the problem. I am really wondering why in any halfway professional development project, you neither use Gradle nor Maven. There, you would simply use a default directory layout and put your _META-INF_ directory into the resource folder. In IntelliJ, you should also be able to manually mark any base folder as a resource folder in the project's module settings.